# is it possible to click on the information given by a tooltip and place it in a list

Tags: javascript

I have mechanical explosion drawings as .svg file that i use in a maintance program
When click on a part of the drawing i get a tooltip with the part number (SAM7629P00835 SCREW)
Is it possible that the tooltip will be clickable and i use the info to place it for example in a orderlist ?

```
<g id="hotspot.80" onmouseover="ShowHotSpot(evt,'80')" onmouseout="HideHotSpot(evt,'80')" onmousemove="ShowToolTip(evt,'80','SAM7629P00835 SCREW')" onclick="javascript:parent.vue_piece(16)" opacity="0">
        <rect x="108.299" y="251.532" width="13.5232" height="11.9322" style="fill:#00ff00;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>
```

I have checked if there was a function conected onclick="javascript:parent.vue_piece(16) but there is no function so if i'm right i can use this to hang a for example a copy the text of the tooltip on it.Can somebody please point me to a example script to use the onclick="javascript:parent.vue_piece(16) function to copy the tooltip text to the system clipboard
Thank you infront for the help

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the implementation of the event handlers. I would look into `"javascript:parent.vue_piece(16)"` the element already has a click action assigned, so maybe adapting it by wrapping it with your version will get you there. If you want the tooltip to be clickable you may need to dig deeper and find out what the **Hide/ShowHotSpot** and **ShowToolTip** are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("ToolTip");
  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
 /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
/* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
```

}

I have add this function and changed

```
<g id="hotspot.0" onmouseover="ShowHotSpot(evt,'0')" onmouseout="HideHotSpot(evt,'0')" onmousemove="ShowToolTip(evt,'0','SAM8834P00009 HOOP')" onclick="myFunction(81)" opacity="0">
        <rect x="116.025" y="298.364" width="13.5232" height="11.9322" style="fill:#00ff00;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>
```

But when i click on Nr. 81 from the drawing i get this error
Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function
myFunction file:///S:/TechnischeDienst/Nieuwe indeling Schema's/Test copy tooltip.svg:12
onclick file:///S:/TechnischeDienst/Nieuwe indeling Schema's/Test copy tooltip.svg:1

Any help would be apriciated